# MS Windows Programming advice for Mac/Unix developer

Tags: windows, winforms, visual-c++, programming-languages, development-environment

I have a few years of experience writing Unix command line tools (no GUI experience) in python, C and C++, and only recently crossed into the GUI world (Cocoa and IOS only). I've learned quite a bit of objective-C and am getting to understand how cocoa MVC works. However, one of the apps I am developing needs a Windows version and I was wondering what a good place to start would be given that I have absolutely no Windows development experience.

I was thinking about using Visual C++ 2010 Express as my development platform (because it's free and because I don't need to learn C++). My application is relatively simple, it will have only two windows and spend most of the time running in the background. It will however need to communicate with the OS (load dll's etc) and an online server (HTTP methods) and I'm not sure whether Visual C++ Express edition gives me access to the required API's. Would a Windows Forms application suffice? Am I going about this the wrong way? Do I need to learn C#? Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are already happy with proper c++, visual Studio C++ express should suit you fine. Given that you are not making a complicated GUI, you don't even need to dip into the managed code - C++ express allows you to create proper c++ console and GUI apps. You also don't need to install the platform SDK - it is part of VS C++ express.

Not being managed C++, you will be able to share source files between your various projects. managed c++, despite the c++ in the name, really is a different enough language that it will be annoying to work with if you simultaneously have to deal with iso C++.

--

Note: The native windows API is a C api, not a C++ framework. So it does not provide a rich set of classes in a coherent framework to deal with. On the other hand, while, large, it is actually quite simple to work with.

Also: Given that you are already familiar with Mac development, there is a LGPL (iirc) package called CFLite that builds on windows and that implements the C api that underlays the Objective-C Cocoa API.

If you use its abstratcions you can share a greater part of code between windows and Mac (and other platforms).

Other C++ IDE's you might want to consider:

- Code::Blocks
- QT Creator

both of which can be configured to use the MINGW port of GCC to windows.

Comment: I'm torn between Python and C++ but since I am more comfortable with C++ I will try out VS C++ for this application. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you'll be better off with c++ than c# if you need more "low-level" stuff. Loading dlls (that is, libs) is simple (pragma comment lib...), as is pure HTTP transfer and communication.

So, VC++ with windows form will suffice, and it is "very c++".

You have access to all global APIs, and loading specific apis like http requires only two lines: one to include wininet header, and other lib (libs are actually "references" to dlls).

Answer (score 1):

If you go the C++ Express way then you need to install Windows SDK separately, and set it up for Visual Studio to use it. And you can't use MFC.

I would however, suggest C#, because it feels like putting little toy bricks together. Easier to debug and maintain. Problem with C# is that it has so many library functions that you can not possibly know if what you want is already made to a function. But that's why we are here :-) If you feel that something you want to do should already exist then ask a question about it. One notable feature that C# lacks is zip archives (it has something similar, but not quite). For zips you can use public libraries, like [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) or [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Is the only downside of using C++ Express putting the pieces together? Are there any advantages of using C# .Net vs C++ .Net?

Comment: C# is by an order of magnitude easier to use that C++. I don't know about C++.NET, never used that combo, it doesn't feel natural to me.

Comment: WinForms and C++ aren't exactly BFFs. Most developers do the UI end of their application in C# and use C++ for the logic methods. If you're looking to truly replicate the experience of XCode/Interface Builder without employing a cross-platform solution, C# and WinForms are really your best option. It's doubtful that a veteran Objective-C programmer will be anything but impressed by the extensiveness of the built-in libraries after a few days of coding in C#.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I wouldn't jump into a whole new API so quickly. Have you considered using Python on Windows? Most of the Python packages I've seen are also available for Windows, so you'll feel at home. And if you need some GUI, you can opt for wxPython, pyGTK or something similar.

For Windows specific things, you can always use ctypes. Especially if they're as simple as loading a DLL.

Comment: I've thought about using Python. In fact when I started the Mac version of the App I was using Py-ObjC but I quickly got rid of the python code and wrote it in pure Obj-C because it turned out to be actually easier--there's a class for almost everything in the Cocoa API and for what I needed to do, Py-ObjC was becoming hackish. The reason I am thinking Windows forms/C++ is because I am trying to draw a parallel to the Interface Builder / Xcode experience.

Comment: The parallel in the Windows world is C#. It's not hard to learn, but if you already know Python and probably have some code already implementing some of the things you need on your Windows application, why move to C#?

Comment: You do have a valid point, are there any limitations I would run into with regards to making Windows API calls if I chose to write the application in Python?

Comment: Structs and pointers will not be too much fun to work with ctypes. COM, as long as there's no automation, will not make you appreciate Windows either. But most basic API doesn't require any of those. And if you do find yourself in need of complex WinAPI, you can always create a DLL/EXE and call that from Python.

Answer (score 0):

have you considered approaching Adobe AIR? it allows you to deploy on Mac, Linux, Windows, iOS, etc. communicating with and launching native processes has been possible since 2.0 and the the latest 2.5 SDK can target Android OS and TVs. with your experience you should be able to pick up ActionScript3 / MXML in no time.

additionally, there are a handful of free IDEs you can use with the Flex and AIR SDKs.  or, if you're a student or low-income developer, you can get a free copy of Flash Builder 4 from Adobe:  http://www.adobe.com/devnet-archive/flex/free/

---

edit:  i believe deploying AIR applications on iPhone requires Flash Professional CS5, which includes the packager for iPhone options.  at the same time, i've read that AIR and other cross-compilers for iOS are painfully slow, so it's perhaps best to develop natively in Objective-C for iOS.

Comment: I've considered cross-platform development (Qt, wxWidgets, etc), but because this application is so small (it took a couple of months (2-3 hrs/week) to develop the Mac version without any prior Objective C experience) I decided it would probably be faster to write it using a Windows IDE in a language I'm already comfortable in (in this case C++). I might consider Adobe AIR once I get into cross-platform development.